# Reactjs 18 render column value by using ReactDOM.render not working due to no longer supported in React 18

Tags: reactjs, database

I am using React Datatable and I want to update the action column value by using createdCell -> ReactDOM.render it's working fine on Reactjs 17 but not working on Reactjs 18.

My code is :

```
columns: [
    { data: 'id', name: 'id', title: 'Id' },
    { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name', title: 'First Name' },
    { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name', title: 'Last Name' },
    { data: 'email', name: 'email', title: 'Email' },
    { data: 'status', name: 'status', title: 'Status' },
    { data: 'action', name: 'action', title: 'Action' }
],
columnDefs: [
    {
        targets: 5,
        createdCell: (td, cellData, records, row, col) => {
            ReactDOM.render(
                <div className="d-flex text-nowrap">
                    Hello
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
]
```

We got a Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as the warning suggests and switch `ReactDOM.render` to `ReactDOM.createRoot`: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html

Comment: ReactDOM.createRoot('What is here') as per our sample code